# Problem while running apt install wine command

Tags: apt, wine

Hello I am new user of linux. And I am trying to install wine on my linux ubunt 16.04. while I'm running the command (apt install wine) it is processing it and in the last it show a message (i have put the picture of that message below) now please tell me what I have to do next

[image]

because I have pressed every key but the message is still there.

Comment: Use your arrow key to get to the `ok` text then press enter

Comment: Thank you George. ;) It works. I've tried every single key since yesterday but failed every time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `arrow keys` on your keyboard to get to the `ok text` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the license.